# Button routing in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a button in material-ui like this:

```
<Button style={green}
        raised="true"
        label="Continue to create group"}>
CREATE NEW GROUP
</Button>
```

What I want is to click on the button and then go to another page inside my app, I'm new to React so I'm playing with basic stuff so I have no clue on how to do it.

Now I go to localhost:3000/ so when I click on the button I want to go to localhost:3000/page1 (for example)

Some help will be nice.

Comment: What does "go to another component" mean here?

Comment: You're right, I just update the question... What I was trying to say is that I want to click on it and then got another page, now I run localhost:3000/ so when I click on the button I want to go to localhost:3000/page1...

Comment: You'll need to add `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router` or similar if you want to mess with the url. You can manipulate props and/or state to otherwise hide/show components.

Answer (score 0):

The good thing about Material-UI buttons is that they share the same functionality as JS buttons (since that's what they are under the hood). As such, you can simply route towards a different component by giving the button an `onClick` event that handles the path you're trying to go to.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `react-router-dom` to handle routing. It takes some setup, but it's not that bad. You can view the full docs here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy.

To get you started though, you'll have to use `this.props.history.push('/path')` to redirect programmatically. An easier solution is to use the built-in `Link` component: `<Link to="/path" />`.